# как сохранить backStack fragment и их содержимое

Tags: android, android-fragment, backstack

есть listview на 1 табе, список дел. нажимаем дело 1, открывается таб2 на нем открывается фрамент понедельник, вводим данные, нажимаем на кнопку далее значения из полей сохраняются в бд, открывается фрагмент вторник тоже поля, чекбокс, тоже самое делаем и таких фрагментов 7. и есть таб3 там список дел, со статусом заполнены они или нет, и при клике на дело должен открыться последний фрагмент с данными.  задача такая: выбрал дело, начал заполнять его и потом переключился на таб 3, и решил заполнить другое дело,  кликаю и перехожу на последний фрагмент. как лучше это реализовать?
вариант 1.
при переключении табов поставить метод, который будет считывать содержимое всех полей и обновлять значения в бд, а при клике на дело будет проверять содержимое ячейки и потом восстанавливать введеные значения и сам фрагмент, но данный метод имеет минус так как не сохраняет сам backstack фрагментов,для каждого элемента
вариант 2.
 написать кастомный Stack Fragment в него ложить фрагменты, при переключении  весь этот стек сериализовать и в бд пихать? но что-то слишком муторно. подскажите как лучше сделать?
Реализовал такой класс:

```
public class SimpleFragmentManager {

    private Stack<Fragment> fragmentStack;

    public SimpleFragmentManager() {
        fragmentStack = new Stack<>();
    }

    public void push(Fragment fragment) {
        fragmentStack.push(fragment);
    }

    public void reset(Fragment fragment) {
        fragmentStack.empty();
        fragmentStack.push(fragment);
    }

    public Fragment pop() {
        return fragmentStack.pop();
    }

    public Fragment peek() {
        return fragmentStack.peek();
    }
}
```

и использую его так :

```
 public void nextStep() {
    Monday monday = new Monday();
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.leftcontent, monday);
    simpleFragmentManager.push(checkData);
    //ft.addToBackStack("monday");
    ft.commit();

}

public void backStep() {
    simpleFragmentManager.pop();
    /*FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    manager.popBackStack();*/
}
```

но вообще не то получается
Чтоб было нагляднее покажу схему:
список дел:

```
дело 1 Fragment1-->fragment2-->fragment3
дело 2 Fragment1-->fragment2
дело 3 Fragment1-->fragment2-->fragment3-->fragment4
```

и получается что при переключении табов необходимо сохранять цепочку для каждого дела, как это делается?